# Debian - chroot ntpd Issues

Tags: ntp, chroot

I would like to configure the ntp daemon inside a chroot enviroment.
The OS I am suing is Debian 9.1, kernel 3.16.0-4-686-pae

The service run as:
/usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -i /var/chroot/ntp -u ntp:ntp -l /var/log/ntpd.log

The problems I face are:

1) The ntp daemon can't resolve DNS name, but its working as expected with IP addressed. Am I missing any special files inside the chroot path?

```
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 1.gr.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 1.europe.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 0.europe.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 0.gr.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 0.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 1.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 2.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
ntpd[2936]: retrying DNS 3.pool.ntp.org: Name or service not known (-2)
```

2) Although the ntp server starts with "-i /var/chroot/ntp" not all paths inside ntpd.conf are relevant to this directory.
For example:

**ntp.conf**:

driftfile **var**/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

logfile **/var**/chroot/ntp/var/log/ntpd.log

Log file requires the whole path; should ntpd be able to access files outside the chroot dir?

Comment: You probably need ``/etc/resolv.conf`` inside the chroot.

Answer (score 1):

When running software inside a chroot, one needs to install essential system libraries and settings inside the chroot for the software to run correctly. For example, linked libraries need to be in chroot. One can use `ldd -v` to show which libraries a particular application uses.

If you run `chroot` so that your chroot directory is `/var/chroot/ntp`, then that will be the `/` directory inside the chroot. So, for example, `logfile /var/chroot/ntp/var/log/ntpd.log` would point to `/var/chroot/ntp/var/chroot/ntp/var/log/ntpd.log` in the main filesystem.

So, in your case you need to set `logfile /var/log/ntpd.log`.

Comment: I have tried logfile /var/log/ntpd.log . ntpd still updates the file in (absolute) path logfile /var/log/ntpd.log instead of /var/chroot/ntp/var/log/ntpd.log

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **partially** solved after changing /etc/nsswitch.conf

From

hosts:          *files* dns

to

hosts:          dns

Now dns queries are working.
The 2nd problem still remains:
PID files and logs must be changed to absolute path instead of relevant to chroot directory.

Is ntp daemon dropping privileges after creating the log files?